# How do we sign a char an integer value in C and take a sum?

Tags: arrays, c, char, integer, clang

I am making a tic-tac-toe game.
I want to assign a char with a value of 4. For eg: I want to assign O with the value of 4 and X with a value of 1. I have tried using

> char O = '4';

But it displays various errors. How do I fix this and assign that character an integer value?
Also I want to take the sum of the values.
Here's the code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int computerPlaysToWin(char board[3][3], int* cRow, int* cCol){
    
        char O='4';
        char X='1';
        int i;
        int j;
    
        
    
    
    
         for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
             for(j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){
                 if ( board[i][j] + board[i][j+1] = 8 ){                      //For rows
                     printf("O", board[i][j+2]);
                 }
    
                 else if ( board[i][j+1] + board[i][j+2] = 8 ){               // For rows
                     printf("O", board[i][j]);
                 }
    
                 else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j] = 8 ){                 // For columns
                     printf("O", board[i+2][j]);
                 }
    
    
                 else if ( board[i+1][j] + board[i+2][j] = 8 ){               //For columns
                      printf("O", board[i][j]);
    
                 }
    
                 else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j+1] = 8 ) {             //For diagonals
                       printf("O", board[i+2][j+2]);
    
                 }
    
                 else if ( board[i+1][j+1] + board[i+2][j+2] = 8 ) {         //For diagonals
                       printf("O", board[i][j]);
    
                 }
    
                 else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j-1] = 8 ) {            //For diagonals
                       printf("O", board[i+2][j-2]);
    
                 }
    
                 else if ( board[i+1][j-1] + board[i+2][j-2] = 8 ) {       //For diagonals
                       printf("O", board[i][j]);
    
                 }
             }
         }
    
    return 0;
    }





int main(void){
char board[3][3];
int row;
int col;

printf("Enter Row: ");
scanf("%d", &row);
printf("Enter column: ");
scanf("%d", &col);
printf("\n");
computerPlaysToWin(board, &row, &col);


}
```

The errors are:

```
> computerPlaysToWin.c:16:47: error: expression is not assignable
>              if ( board[i][j] + board[i][j+1] = 8 ){                      //For rows
>                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 


computerPlaysToWin.c:17:30: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                  printf("O", board[i][j+2]);
>                         ~~~  ^ computerPlaysToWin.c:20:54: error: expression is not assignable
>              else if ( board[i][j+1] + board[i][j+2] = 8 ){               // For rows
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 



computerPlaysToWin.c:21:30: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                  printf("O", board[i][j]);
>                         ~~~  ^ computerPlaysToWin.c:24:52: error: expression is not assignable
>              else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j] = 8 ){                 // For columns
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 



computerPlaysToWin.c:25:30: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                  printf("O", board[i+2][j]);
>                         ~~~  ^ computerPlaysToWin.c:29:54: error: expression is not assignable
>              else if ( board[i+1][j] + board[i+2][j] = 8 ){               //For columns
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 



computerPlaysToWin.c:30:31: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                   printf("O", board[i][j]);
>                          ~~~  ^ computerPlaysToWin.c:34:54: error: expression is not assignable
>              else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j+1] = 8 ) {             //For diagonals
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 



computerPlaysToWin.c:35:32: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                    printf("O", board[i+2][j+2]);
>                           ~~~  ^ computerPlaysToWin.c:39:58: error: expression is not assignable
>              else if ( board[i+1][j+1] + board[i+2][j+2] = 8 ) {         //For diagonals
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 



computerPlaysToWin.c:40:32: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                    printf("O", board[i][j]);
>                           ~~~  ^ computerPlaysToWin.c:44:54: error: expression is not assignable
>              else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j-1] = 8 ) {            //For diagonals
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 



computerPlaysToWin.c:45:32: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                    printf("O", board[i+2][j-2]);
>                           ~~~  ^ computerPlaysToWin.c:49:58: error: expression is not assignable
>              else if ( board[i+1][j-1] + board[i+2][j-2] = 8 ) {       //For diagonals
>                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ 




computerPlaysToWin.c:50:32: warning: data argument not used by format
> string [-Wformat-extra-args]
>                    printf("O", board[i][j]);
>                           ~~~  ^ 8 warnings and 8 errors generated.
```

Comment: If you want to assign the [ASCII code](https://www.asciitable.com/) of the character `4` (which is `52`) to the variable `O`, then `char O = '4';` is correct. However, if you want to assign it the value `4` instead of `52`, then you must write `char O = 4;`. EDIT: This comment was made before you edited the question by adding that you also want to produce a sum.

Comment: That line of code is valid. It assigns the integer value `0x34` to `O`. If you get errors, it is not from this line. But as you do not show the error messages and also not the other code that would be needed to compile, no one can help.

Comment: That line does not handle the "and X with a value of 1" and also "take the sum". Please provide minimal complete code to reproduce. Also provide error messages.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator in C and you should use `==` operator to check equality. Also it is unclear for me what you want to do by `printf` statements like `printf("O", board[i][j]);`. These `printf` statement are valid (the extra arguments like `board[i][j]` are ignored), but it don't use the assigned variable `O` nor `X`.

Comment: Also note that typically `'4' + '4'` won't be `8`. It also won't be `'8'`. `('4' - '0') + ('4' - '0')` will be `8` because it is guaranteed in C that character codes of numbers are continuous.

Comment: If you can explain how `board[i][j] + board[i][j+1] = 8` makes sense, then I'll point out the error for you next.

Comment: BTW: Your array does not contain any defined values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```c
void computerPlaysToWin(char board[3][3], int* cRow, int* cCol){

    char O='4';
    char X='1';
    int i;
    int j;
    
     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
         for(j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){
             if ( board[i][j] + board[i][j+1] == 8 ){                      //For rows
                 printf("O %c", board[i][j+2]);
             }

             else if ( board[i][j+1] + board[i][j+2] == 8 ){               // For rows
                 printf("O %c", board[i][j]);
             }

             else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j] == 8 ){                 // For columns
                 printf("O %c", board[i+2][j]);
             }

             else if ( board[i+1][j] + board[i+2][j] == 8 ){               //For columns
                  printf("O %c", board[i][j]);
             }

             else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j+1] == 8 ) {             //For diagonals
                   printf("O %c", board[i+2][j+2]);
             }

             else if ( board[i+1][j+1] + board[i+2][j+2] == 8 ) {         //For diagonals
                   printf("O %c", board[i][j]);
             }

             else if ( board[i][j] + board[i+1][j-1] == 8 ) {            //For diagonals
                   printf("O %c", board[i+2][j-2]);
             }

             else if ( board[i+1][j-1] + board[i+2][j-2] == 8 ) {       //For diagonals
                   printf("O %c", board[i][j]);
             }
         }
     }
}

int main(void){
    char board[3][3];
    int row;
    int col;

    printf("Enter Row: ");
    scanf("%d", &row);
    printf("Enter column: ");
    scanf("%d", &col);
    printf("\n");
    computerPlaysToWin(board, &row, &col);
}
```

Comment: `%d` is more likely to match the intention. Given the addition is expected to result in 8, there are probably no values of printable characters in that array.

Comment: `for(j = 0; j < 3 ; j++){ if ( board[i][j] + board[i][j+1] == 8 )` attempts to access `board[][]` outside its bounds --> UB.  Code needs re-work.